# Getting breadcrumbs all parent rows in one SQL query with languages table

Tags: mysql, breadcrumbs

Hello i need to take all breadcrumbs links(url, text) in one mysql query.
With current language, language translations(text) in table pages_text.
Ulr and parent_id in table pages.

So i need all parents rows with current language.

i have 2 tables

1: pages

id name      parent_id url

```
1 Home       0        (some url)
2 About      1        (some url)
3 Contact    1        (some url)
4 Legal      2        (some url)
5 Privacy    4        (some url)
6 Products   1        (some url)
7 Support    1        (some url)
```

2: pages_text

id name                pages_id languages_id

```
1 Main                 0        2
2 About                1        1
3 (different languges) 1        3
4 (different languges) 2        4
5 (different languges) 4        2
6 (different languges) 1        1
7 (different languges) 1        2
```

There are some working code with one table getting full parents row.

Can u help me to change this code for 2 tables.

```
id  name    parent_id
---------------------------
1   Home        0
2   About       1
3   Contact     1
4   Legal       2
5   Privacy     4
6   Products    1
7   Support     1



SELECT T2.id, T2.name
    FROM (
        SELECT
            @r AS _id,
            @p := @r AS previous,
            (SELECT @r := parent_id FROM table1 WHERE id = _id) AS parent_id,
            @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
        FROM
            (SELECT @r := 5, @p := 0, @l := 0) vars,
            table1 h
        WHERE @r <> 0 AND @r <> @p) T1
    JOIN table1 T2
    ON T1._id = T2.id
    ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code full chain breadcrumbs with languages 2 tables:

```
SELECT T2.id, T2.name, T3.plates_title
    FROM (
        SELECT
            @r AS _id,
            @p := @r AS previous,
            (SELECT @r := parent_id FROM pages WHERE id = _id) AS parent_id,
            @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
        FROM
            (SELECT @r := 121, @p := 0, @l := 0) vars,
            pages h
        WHERE @r <> 0 AND @r <> @p) T1
    JOIN pages T2
    ON T1._id = T2.id
    JOIN pages_text T3 
    ON T1._id = T3.pages_id where T3.languages_id = 1
    ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC
```